# Reverse engineering a mysqldump output with MySQL Workbench gives "statement starting from pointed line contains non UTF8 characters" error

Tags: utf-8, import, mysql-workbench, mysql

I have a huge .sql file from a mysqldump command. I ran this file in MySQL workbench and it seems to create the tables fine. But it gives the following error log

```
ERROR: Line 49076: SQL statement starting from pointed line contains non UTF8 characters. Statement skipped.

ERROR: Line 49077: SQL statement starting from pointed line contains non UTF8 characters. Statement skipped.

ERROR: Line 49078: SQL statement starting from pointed line contains non UTF8 characters. Statement skipped.

// Loads more skipped statements //

ERROR: Line 55722: SQL statement starting from pointed line contains non UTF8 characters. Statement skipped.
```

Is this something to worry about? it seems that the tables all build correctly.

I can't even get in and have a look at the lines that contain non UTF8 characters since the file is so big I can't open it with my installed text editors. If I could `grep` lines 49076 - 55722 and write to a txt file that would be ideal but I'm not sure how to `grep` specific lines.

**Edit 1**

So after running the suggested

```
sed -n '49076,49078p' dumpfile.sql > mydump.txt
```

I found that this section is huge for 3 lines of code (5.27 MB). They contain insert into statements that become unreadable at the end.

Sample

```
M@ÙØ©Å”mT@œ ´`wM@¯\r™þÙlT@”cØM@÷îˆlT@DòjNM@Çægö-lT@ìzÐÜØM@iW¥\0lT@Ì¸I5ýL@ùÌlT@Ä„8ÿDøL@÷]•MlT@6øëãôL@…
```

theses appear at the ends of the statements,

```
// actual data above for insert into statement //
81.752505329767487,59.287405619999873 81.742705329767475)))
','\0\0\0\0\0\0\0Œ\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0|Àó ¸E@€]ß< C)@ìXÓåb·E@±Sa·B)
@$®³E@ Þÿ¦J)@üsqDŒ²E@X\ZÃQ=L)@DUìX:²E@îî¶VN)@üQtM²E@0¥À·4Q)@<wéO°²E@€vR3U)@<™æF&³
// seemingly random characters for thousands of lines bellow//
```

Is this a corrupted copy? or some other underlying problem with the way my database is condfigured?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279

Comment: Try using `$ sed -n '49076,49078p' dumpfile.sql` or using `$ perl -pe 'undef $_ unless $. >= 49076 && $. <= 49078' dumpfile.sql`

Comment: I certainly would be worried if I get such warnings. Seems like you have fed in a dump in a different encoding than utf-8. Dumps created by MySQL Workbench are always utf-8 encoded. Perhaps you have used a different source?

Comment: @MikeLischke I created the dump on my ubuntu server with the command `mysqldump`